# Java : How to receive REST transactions in strict order?

Tags: java

I want to receive REST messages in a strict order.

For example:

```
authorize-> capture -> refund
```

Requests example:

```
<transaction>
   <type>authorize</type>
</transaction>

<transaction>
   <type>capture</type>
</transaction>

<transaction>
   <type>refund</type>
</transaction>
```

**Is there some way in Java to create a data structure and compare the order in this case type and in addition to that, I want to matched correctly against the proper order.**

*Can you give me advice please?*

Comment: If each request has unique ID then you can use a `Map` with that Id as a key and type of last transaction as a value. So when you get next transaction for given Id you can check current type and new type and process accordingly. You can wrap this into you own class which will be wrapper around `Map`

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Comment: Do you want to receive or process in this order ?

Comment: I to achieve both. Can you show me code example please?

Comment: Where have you stored this `<transaction>
   <type>authorize</type>
</transaction>

<transaction>
   <type>capture</type>
</transaction>

<transaction>
   <type>refund</type>
</transaction>` ?

Comment: Into JAXB Objext

Comment: No, I meant to say have you written this in a file ? If yes, then which file with extension ?

Comment: No I store it in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use this in a nice, well- structured way, an idea would be to organise this workflow in the [Factory Design Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm). Each REST Transaction would be stored in an object and then you will have full control over them.

You can have an interface ¨RestTransaction¨ that is implemented by the classes ¨AuthorizeTransaction¨ , ¨CaptureTransaction¨ and ¨RefundTransaction¨. Then you will have a class ¨TransactionFactory¨ which will generate the objects. Each time a REST transaction is registered the TransactionFactory class would start working to create the specific Transaction object.

[Here](https://vaadin.com/tutorials/consuming-rest-services-from-java-applications) you can find more information about how you should model your data, fetch it and then consume it in Java.

In this way you will have full,structured control over the information flowing through your transaction: ordering and processing in any way you want.

As your model classes should be configured by yourself regarding to your own needs I will emphasize a code example sample on how to work with the REST responses JSON

```
@ApplicationScoped

public class JsonService {

@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "yourapikey.apikey")
private String apikey;

private Client client;
private WebTarget target;

@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    //your query params
    target = client.target(
            "YOUR API URL").queryParam("param1", "10")
            .queryParam("param2", "json")
            .queryParam("param3", "metric")
            .queryParam("paramN", apikey)
            ;
}

public TransactionResponse getTransaction(String type) {
// the parameter would be one of your type of request( the one you want to order )
    return target.queryParam("q", type)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(TransactionResponse.class);
} }
```

Please look carefully at all the links that I have gave you. There are plenty of code examples in there for everything that I have mentioned.

Comment: I gave you some code example suitable for your use-case, but please check carefully the links I have sent you. You have complete examples there. Good luck !

Comment: No. It is just for Java EE.